# Apache Ignite : How to fix this error Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception

Tags: ignite

Getting this error Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception  while starting ignite(apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin).

Trying restarting the instance and increasing the onheap and offheap memory.

we tried another version apache-ignite-fabric-2.5.0-bin got the same error.

Any suggestion or configuration i need to do to fix this issue.

```
[06:06:33,024][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#40][ClientListenerProcessor] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Invalid handshake message
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioServerBuffer.read(ClientListenerNioServerBuffer.java:115)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerBufferedParser.decode(ClientListenerBufferedParser.java:60)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerBufferedParser.decode(ClientListenerBufferedParser.java:40)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3490)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1113)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2339)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2110)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1764)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you provide full logs from all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why there will be activity on ODBC port when you start Apache Ignite instance. Are you sure that no applications are trying to connect to Ignite ports, send garbage to sockets when you bring Ignite up?

Maybe there's something which confuses Ignite for their buddy.